# No module named _view when bundling a pygame application

Tags: python, macos, console, pygame, py2app

So I have made a simple Tic-Tac-Toe game using python/pygame, and I am trying to convert it to an app using py2app. If you want to see the source code, it's right here. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1GtBgVnF6HDXELjuhmjIUgKDhGAPyKszCM-Z3HivgDX4/edit?usp=sharing

I have used this exact same process before and it has worked in the past.

So I saved this as "TicTacToe.py" to my desktop, and created a program called "Setup.py" on my desktop.
The code for setup.py is

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    app = ['TicTacToe.py'],
    setup_requires = ['py2app'],
    )
```

Then I open my terminal and type

```
cd desktop
rm -rf build dist
python setup.py py2app
```

After running, there are two new folders in my desktop, one labeled build and another labeled dist. In the dist folder, I find TicTacToe.app and I run it. However, when I try to run it, it says "TicTacToe error, Terminate or open console?"

In the console, there are about a dozen errors, here are a few as examples.

```
(ImportError: no module named _view)

RuntimeWarning: import display: no module named _view

RuntimeWarning: import draw: no module named _view
```

and a bunch of others when it trys to import pixelcopy, image, transform

I took a screen shot of the console so that you can see most of the errors. 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_genGXpST77WjNjUXdGcXpHclk/edit?usp=sharing
Also, if it helps at all, I am on a macbook pro running 10.7.5, and I am using python 2.7

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure what happens here, for some reason a module named "_view" is not added to your application bundle. I do know that bundling pygame can be annoyingly hard, but haven't had time yet to research a solution for that yet.

Comment: Random guess: maybe it doesn't like applications with hyphens in the name. Try renaming it to TicTacToe.py

Comment: Thanks for taking a stab at it Kev, but unfortunately that didn't do anything.